# How to change color of fixed element depending on the color of background content?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, colors, mix-blend-mode

I have a fixed element and a lot of different content on the page. I need this fixed element to become black or white, depending on the dominant color on it's back when scrolling.

How to do it?  I don't know what height page sections would be, what color is the first section of the page, and I'm using vue/nuxt if that may help.

```css
.section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.section_type_white {
  background-color: white;
}

.section_type_blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.section_type_yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.section_type_black {
  background-color: black;
}

.section_type_red {
  background-color: red;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  
}

.fixed-element {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
/*   border: 1px solid black; */
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-element"></div>

<section class="page">
  <section class="section section_type_blue"></section>
  <section class="section section_type_white"></section>
  <section class="section section_type_image">
    <img class="image" src="https://yobte.ru/uploads/posts/2019-11/devushki-v-sinih-platjah-82-foto-15.jpg"
  </section>
  <section class="section section_type_yellow"></section>
  <section class="section section_type_black"></section>
  <section class="section section_type_red"></section>
</section>
```

Comment: I have an idea, but I'd like to ask- what color bg do you expect when the underlying bg is red? Or yellow? Or anything other than white/black (which is obvious)?

Comment: @NickDawes I wish this question would be handled by script. I think black will be better seen on light background like yellow, and vice verse, white is better for blue or dark background. I've seen on youtube once a tutorial how to teach element to recognize wheather background  is light or not using neural networks, but I can't find it. And I'm not sure that I can handle neural networks)

Comment: The best I can suggest is to use CSS's backdrop-filter, and apply both the ```saturation(0)``` and ```invert(1)``` functions, in that order. The first will drain all the colour from the background, the second will invert the background to contrast what lies beneath. This works for perfectly black or white backgrounds, but you'll end up with shades of gray for anything else (blues, yellows etc). I believe it offers sufficient contrast, but if it's absolutely necessary for your design to achieve either black or white, I'm afraid I can't think of any solution.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the color thief plugin for jQuery. you can get the dominant color or even a pallete of an image using it and experiment with inverting the fixed element color or shifting it accordingly. Some references are [here](https://awik.io/grab-dominant-color-image-jquery/), [here](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) and [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Image-Color-Palette-Generating-Plugin-Color-Thief.html).